# Check for changes on Git Repository : BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am new to `git` so if you find my question stupid, just let me know and I will remove it.

So I have "push"ed a project to my private repository. Next day, I wanted to list all files that needs to be "pull"ed and "merge"d before I start my work. In other words I wanted to list all files that has been changed and pushed.

So what I did, I changed a file online, through BitBucket online editor and committed. But when I check on local for "diff", it doesn't list that file.

What am I missed here?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many git commands and combination of commands to figure that out. The easiest, and in most cases I always use

```
git status or 
sudo git status
```

in the checked out repo or in the cloned repo to figure out what changed.

Comment: `git status` says - Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
do I need to do something extra from online editor? I already have committed and approved it.

Comment: that's why, if something was modifed or edited it would ask you to commit or say "Modified" next to the filename. You need to edit bunch of files in order to check for changes.

Comment: not sure I am getting you at this point. I simply whats to check remote repository for any changed file.

Comment: ic. then you need to issue > git pull.

Comment: i think git pull = git fetch then git merge. isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I get it now. its first `git fetch` then to check for the difference you need to use `git diff origin origin/master` one you confirm, you do `git merge` to apply changes.